# Convert data time string to date time

Tags: php, time

I have problem on converting my string date to php date format my string: **2020-08-04 13:00:06 (Asia/Kolkata)**

and i am want to convert it to: **2020-08-04 13:00:06**

my code is below:

```
<?php
    
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2020-08-04 13:00:06 (Asia/Kolkata)'));
echo $date;
```

But its result is not correct, its showing result as: **1969-12-31 19:00:00**

So can you please help me on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you only want to cut of the timezone part, do you actually need to go through the date functions? A simple split on the second space would yield the same result?!

Answer (score 1):

Your string can be interpreted correctly with DateTime if the parentheses in the string are removed.

```
$string = "2020-08-04 13:00:06 (Asia/Kolkata)";
$cleanString = str_replace(['(',')'],'',$string);
$date = new DateTime($cleanString);
var_dump($date);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-08-04 13:00:06.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Asia/Kolkata" }
```

The DateTime object also has the correct time zone. The output can be done using the format method:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//2020-08-04 13:00:06
```

Answer (score -1):

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2020-08-04 13:00:06'));
echo $date;

Answer (score -2):

Please use this code

```
$date = substr("2020-08-04 13:00:06 (Asia/Kolkata)",0,19);
echo $date;
```